# how to add values for each colum for each day?

Tags: php, html, mysqli, sum

I have a Table which  Input all the necessary data to do statistics. i now face the issue that i dont know how to add up the values for each colum but that it only adds the values up for each day. and then Displays it in a row or another Table.

this Code is what i use to call out all of the values and insert them into a table

```html
<html>
<head>
<title>Your Home Page</title>
    </head><body>
<table border="1">
  <tr>
    <th>Date</th>
    <th>Participant ID</th>
    <th>Gender</th>
    <th>Hand</th>
    <th>Udnder 18</th>
    <th>Adult</th>
    <th>R</th>
    <th>C</th>
    <th>L</th>
    <th>Cash</th>
    <th>Card</th>
    <th>Ammount</th>
  </tr>
  <?php
    $servername = "localhost";
    $username = "root";
    $password = "";
    $dbname = "***";
    
    $mysqli = new mysqli($servername, $username, $password, $dbname);

if ($mysqli->connect_error) {
    die("Connection failed: " . $mysqli->connect_error);
} 
  $sql = "SELECT * FROM table ORDER BY Date ASC"; 
  $result = mysqli_query($mysqli, $sql) or die(mysqli_error());

  $datum = '';
  while($set = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)) {
    ?>
      <tr>
        <td>
          <?php 
          if ($datum == $set["Date"]) {
            echo '&nbsp;';
          } else {
            echo $set["Date"];
          }
          ?>
        </td>
            <td><?php echo $set["ParticipantID"]; ?></td>
            <td><?php echo $set["Gender"]; ?></td>
            <td><?php echo $set["Hand"]; ?></td>
            <td><?php echo $set["Under18"]; ?></td>
            <td><?php echo $set["Adult"]; ?></td>
            <td><?php echo $set["r"]; ?></td>
            <td><?php echo $set["c"]; ?></td>
            <td><?php echo $set["l"]; ?></td>
            <td><?php echo $set["Cash"]; ?></td>
            <td><?php echo $set["Card"]; ?></td>
            <td><?php echo $set["Ammount"]; ?></td>
      </tr>
    <?php $datum = $set["Date"]; ?>
  <?php
  }
  ?>
</table> </body></html>
```

[image]

So for 04-01-2018 for the colum R the total summed up value should be 2. etc.

Thanks for the help.
Kind Regards
Mark

Comment: For Jan 4th R should be 2 for all 4 records, or just the 4th row (0, 0, 1, 2)?

Comment: Yes, maybe it is possible to insert it then into that table under the last row for Jan 4th as a TOTAL row @Ctznkane525

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The first way of solving this problem is to use the second MySQL query to get total values for each date. After that create a function `printDateTableRow` to print each row of the table. Using the `mysqli_fetch_assoc($totalMysqliResult)` parameter of this function, you can pass values of a row with total values for each new date.

Another way is to use the the [`WITH ROLLUP`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/group-by-modifiers.html) group modifier (you can try to write such query by yourself).

Here is the working code for the first way:

```
<html>
<head>
    <title>Your Home Page</title>
</head>
<body>
<table border="1">
  <tr>
    <th>Date</th>
    <th>Participant ID</th>
    <th>Gender</th>
    <th>Hand</th>
    <th>Udnder 18</th>
    <th>Adult</th>
    <th>R</th>
    <th>C</th>
    <th>L</th>
    <th>Cash</th>
    <th>Card</th>
    <th>Ammount</th>
  </tr>
  <?php
    $servername = "localhost";
    $username = "root";
    $password = "";
    $dbname = "***";

    $mysqli = new mysqli($servername, $username, $password, $dbname);

if ($mysqli->connect_error) {
    die("Connection failed: " . $mysqli->connect_error);
}
  $sql = "SELECT * FROM `table` ORDER BY Date ASC";
  $result = mysqli_query($mysqli, $sql) or die(mysqli_error($mysqli));


$totalMysqliResult = mysqli_query($mysqli, '
    SELECT
        Date, "" AS ParticipantID, "" AS Gender, "" AS Hand,
        SUM(Under18) AS date_total_Under18,
        SUM(Adult) AS date_total_Adult, SUM(r) AS date_total_r,
        SUM(c) AS date_total_с, SUM(l) AS date_total_l,
        SUM(Cash) AS date_total_Cash, SUM(Card) AS date_total_Card,
        SUM(Amount) AS date_total_Amount
    FROM `table`
    GROUP BY Date
    ORDER BY Date ASC') or die(mysqli_error($mysqli));

/**
* @param $row
* @param null $dateFieldHeader
*/
function printDateTableRow($row, $dateFieldHeader = null) {
  ?><tr><?
  foreach ($row as $key => $curVal) {
      ?><td><?
      if ($key == 'Date') {
          echo $dateFieldHeader == null ? $curVal : $dateFieldHeader;
      } else {
          echo $curVal;
      }
      ?></td><?
  }
  ?></tr><?
}

$previousDate = null;
$oneDateRowsCount = 0;

while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)) {
    if ($row['Date'] == $previousDate) {
        $oneDateRowsCount++;
        printDateTableRow($row, '&nbsp;');
    } else {

        if ($previousDate !== null) {
            printDateTableRow(mysqli_fetch_assoc($totalMysqliResult), 'Date total');
        }

        printDateTableRow($row);
        $oneDateRowsCount = 1;
    }

    $previousDate = $row['Date'];
}

// add total for the last rows with the same date
if ($oneDateRowsCount > 1) {
    printDateTableRow(mysqli_fetch_assoc($totalMysqliResult), 'Date total');
}
?>
</body>
</html>
```

You should refactor this code in OOP style and use [PDO](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/pdo/info) instead of mysqli.

Comment: Thank you so much for you're help. Why do you suggest i should convert it into PDO and use OOP? whats the benifit of doing so?

Comment: is there also a way that i could Change the Background Color for the row where the totals are added up to Change it to a different Color then White? @camelsWriteInCamelCase